# Including components with a clickonce installation - what is the correct way?

Tags: clickonce, microsoft-sync-framework

I have a clickonce application that makes use of the sync framework, version 2.1.
I would like it so that all files nessessary to run the application come bundled with it.

In my publish settings, under Application Files, I have flagged the following files to be included:

- microsoft.synchronization.data.dll
- microsoft.synchronization.data.server.dll
- microsoft.synchronization.data.sqlserver.dll
- microsoft.synchronization.sqlserverce.dll
- microsoft.synchronization

This seems to nagate the need for the istaller to download anything extra.
However, the target of the application is 32bit. If the application is installed on a 64bit machine then it will error when a sync is performed with the following:

```
...failed due to the following error 80040154 class not registered regdb-e-class not registered...
```

The fix for this will be for the user to install the 32bit version of the sync framework redistributable from here: [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c3b2f32b-12a9-40b8-9e83-c452ac546c49&displaylang=en)

What am I doing wrong with the publish settings for this to be the case? Ideally, Id like the application to be able to be installed and run without the need to download anything extra.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to have two deployments, one for 64-bit machines that includes the 64-bit assemblies, and one for 32-bit machines that includes the 32-bit assemblies.

Your other choice is to take the redistributable for the Sync Framework and create a custom prerequisite for it using the Bootstrapper Manifest Generator; there might be a check in the BMG that will check the OS, I'm not sure. If not, this doesn't behoove you of course.